# Boost regex cpp for finding strings between %% with output excluding the % character itself

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am having a problem with boost regex in cpp. I want to match a string like
"Hello %world% regex %cpp%" and expected string output is world, cpp

Can somebody suggest a regex for this

Thanks
Anil

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `\%(.*?)\%`smallest group

Online regex: https://regex101.com/r/dSCE2a/2

And for the code with boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    boost::cmatch mat;
    boost::regex reg( "\\%(.*?)\\%" );
    char szStr[] = "Hello %world% regex %cpp%";
    char *where = szStr;
    while (regex_search(where, mat, reg))
    {
        cout << mat[1] << endl; // 0 for whole match, 1 for sub
        where = (char*)mat[0].second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer `"\\%([^\\%]*)\\%"` (or as a raw string `R"r(\%([^\%]*)\%)r"`)

It doesn't rely on non-greedy qualifiers

Which is essentially

- one percent character `\\%`
- any amount of non-percent characters `[^\\%]*`
- one percent character `\\%`

I know this is tagged boost but here's a solution with std::regex

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string source = "Hello %world%";
    regex match_percent_enclosed (R"_(\%([^\%]*)\%)_");
    smatch between_percent;

    bool found_match = regex_search(source,between_percent,match_percent_enclosed);
    if(found_match && between_percent.size()>1)
        cout << "found: \"" << between_percent[1].str() << "\"." << endl; 
    else
        cout << "no match found." << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may get some idea

```
   %(.+?)%
```

Result:

```
Match 1
1.  world
Match 2
1.  cpp
```